# Comprehensions: multiple values per iteration

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

Is there a way to output two (or more) items per iteration in a list/dictionary/set comprehension? As a simple example, to output all the positive and negative doubles of the integers from 1 to 3 (that is to say, `{x | x = ±2n, n ∈ {1...3}}`), is there a syntax similar to the following?

```
>>> [2*i, -2*i for i in range(1, 4)]
[2, -2, 4, -4, 6, -6]
```

I know I could output tuples of `(+i,-i)` and flatten that, but I was wondering if there was any way to completely solve the problem using a single comprehension.

Currently, I am producing two lists and concatenating them (which works, provided the order isn't important):

```
>>> [2*i for i in range(1, 4)] + [-2*i for i in range(1, 4)]
[2, 4, 6, -2, -4, -6]
```

Comment: Note that if order isn't important, you are probably using the wrong data structure - `{2*i for i in range(1, 4)} | {-2*i for i in range(1, 4)}`.

Comment: @Lattyware That has the side effect of uniquifying the pool of output items, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Hence the *probably* - if you need duplicates, yes, sets are unsuitable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another form of nested comprehension:

```
>>> [sub for i in range(1, 4) for sub in (2*i, -2*i)]
[2, -2, 4, -4, 6, -6]
```

Answer (score 12):

Another option is a nested comprehension:

```
r = [2*i*s for i in range(1, 4) for s in (1, -1)]
```

For a more general case:

```
r = [item for tpl in (<something that yields tuples>) for item in tpl]
```

with your original example:

```
r = [item for tpl in ((2*i, -2*i) for i in range(1, 4)) for item in tpl]
```

although I'd really suggest `itertools.chain.from_iterable` as @Lattyware said.

Comment: Note that this generally has worse performance that flattening using `itertools` and is generally very hard to read (nested list comprehensions are generally abhorred by newbies due to the lack of an obvious order to read in).

Comment: @Lattyware Could you elaborate on why this would have worse performance?

Comment: @Asad `itertools.chain` was written specifically to do the job of flattering an iterable, and does so very efficiently. The list comp is just slightly slower - I remember seeing benchmarked results on a 'how to flatten a list' question a while back. Not that performance is really the main issue - readability is, performance only matters in rare, rare cases. Readability always does.

Comment: While this works in this specific case (multiplication), I think a more generalisable approach would be `[2*s for i in range(1, 4) for s in i, -i`. The idiom here doesn't work for more complex functions.

Answer (score 10):

The best answer here is to simply use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to, as you mention, flatten the list:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable((2*i, -2*i) for i in range(1, 4))
```

This is pretty readable, and doesn't require iterating over the source twice (which may be problematic given some iterators can be exhausted, and it means extra computational effort).

Comment: Thanks. This is a good solution, but I generally avoid importing stuff unless I have to. I'll have to add itertools to my arsenal at some point though, so +1

Comment: There is no reason to reinvent the wheel when something exists in the standard library - there is no reason to fear `import`. `itertools` is a great part of Python (just check out how many SO Python answers use it). It's fast, efficient, and does a ton of stuff so you don't have to.

Answer (score 6):

Although I would use the `itertools` method @Lattyware suggested, here is a more general approach using a generator that may also be helpful.

```
>>> def nums():
        for i in range(1, 4):
            yield 2*i
            yield -2*i


>>> list(nums())
[2, -2, 4, -4, 6, -6]
```

Comment: +1, it's a good enough way to do it, generators also tend to be surprisingly fast.

Comment: @Lattyware I would +1 you as well but I ran out of them

Comment: @Lattyware Yesterday, I'll have to be more careful with them from now on.

Comment: Bah, no point denying a good answer an upvote just in case there is another one later.

Answer (score 2):

According to [PEP202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) there is no way to output more than one object from a list comprehension:

> - The form `[x, y for ...]` is disallowed; one is required to write
>         `[(x, y) for ...]`.

Comment: This is only true in 3.x+, IIRC. In 2.x, you could use the former method to construct a tuple, but in 3.x, it was changed to match generator expressions where the brackets were required to resolve an ambiguity in the syntax (as in 3.x, list comps and their brethren are just syntactic sugar around generator expressions).

Comment: Just to be clear - in either version, you just get a tuple, not multiple items in the list.